# Bootstrap grid layout when div is removed

Tags: bootstrap-4

So I am working with a dashboard look that has the possibility of having four 'squares' that can be switched on and role dependant on a users role.

The top row usually is left as it so has square around 30% and the other is around 70% width. This is fine.

However, on the bottom row of the dashboard, you can have two squares. When the two are switched on then my current grid setup works just fine but when a user has one square 'hidden' then the other square doesn't take up the whole row.

This is what I have so far. I can't post any of the elements that are in it but here's the outline.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-5"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-8 col-sm-7"></div>

</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-6">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-8 col-sm-6">
    </div>
</div>
```

Any solution to this or will I have to work on some sort of backend logic to find out if a user has all four columns shown or just three?

Comment: When both of the bottom squares are shown, are they always equal width, or are they also 70/30?

Comment: @Zim Always equal width so they should be 50% each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [auto-layout `col` columns](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/#auto-layout-columns) which will fill the width...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/Y0WwVS7KMd

Comment: So if I have it like this and the second col was 'hidden', the top col should fill the remainder of the width?

Comment: @RobertMcAteer If you set it to hidden it won't as the element still exists. Set it to `display: none;` and your top col will expand.

Comment: @Zim yeah. Got it to work now. Thanks for your solution!